# How to move button in array and set null of come from?

Tags: c#, button

I have the multi-dimensional array `originalArray[X_VECTOR, Y_VECTOR]` of `MyButtons`.

MyButton is simple created class (maybe unnecessary):

```
class MyButton : Button
{
    private int[] id;

    public MyButton()
    {
        id = new int[2];
    }

    public int[] ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }

        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In loop we fill the array of buttons:

```
public void fillArray() {
    originalArray = new MyButton[X_VECTOR, Y_VECTOR];
    int count_buttons = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < X_VECTOR; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y_VECTOR; ++j)
        {
            count_buttons++;
            MyButton btn = new MyButton();
            btn.Name = "btn " + count_buttons;
            btn.ID[0] = i;
            btn.ID[1] = j;
            originalArray[i, j] = btn;   
        }
     }
}
```

Now, we would like to `move button to right side after click` in array:

```
protected void MyBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sender != null) {
        MyButton myclickbutton = (MyButton)sender;
        int x = myclickbutton.ID[0];
        int y = myclickbutton.ID[1];

        MyButton temp = originalArray[x, y];
        temp.Location = new Point(curr_pos_x + 55, curr_pos_y);
        temp.ID[0] = x; 
        temp.ID[1] = y + 1; // new coordinate y
        originalArray[x, y + 1] = temp;
        temp = null;
        // originalArray[x, y] = null;
    }
}
```

**NULL is not set**. What I'm going wrong?

I need this ilustration:

`BEFORE CLICK:`

```
originalArray[0,0] = btn instance; 
originalArray[0,1] = null;
```

`AFTER CLICK:`

```
originalArray[0,0] = null; 
originalArray[0,1] = btn instance;
```

**EDIT:**
When I tried this:

```
protected void MyBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sender != null) {
        MyButton myclickbutton = (MyButton)sender;
        int x = myclickbutton.ID[0];
        int y = myclickbutton.ID[1];

        myclickbutton.Location = new Point(curr_pos_x + 55, curr_pos_y);
        myclickbutton.ID[0] = x;
        myclickbutton.ID[1] = y + 1;
        originalArray[x, y + 1] = myclickbutton;
        originalArray[x, y] = null;
    }
}
```

That maybe OK, but when I was testing this

```
if ((originalArray[i, j].Name == testArray[i, j].Name)) ...
```

This line gets me `NullReferenceException`.

This function I same like fillArray above, and this I call in constructor:

```
public void createTestArray() {
        testArray = new MyButton[X_VECTOR, Y_VECTOR];
        int count_buttons = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < X_VECTOR; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y_VECTOR; ++j)
            {
                count_buttons++;
                MyButton btn = new MyButton();
                btn.Name = "btn " + count_buttons;
                testArray[i, j] = btn;   
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: When you debug, which line raises the exception?

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code that the click event handler is associated with any of your `MyButton` instances.  If you are still sure the event is being handled, put a breakpoint on the event handler and step through the code when you click the button.

Comment: Do you receive `NullReferenceException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException`. If it is the latter before assigning `originalArray[x, y + 1]` assert that `y < Y_VECTOR - 1`.

Comment: ... how is it possible to set ID's two array values separately while it is has a setter which takes an array? Does this work anyway?

Comment: Why have you commented `originalArray[x,y] = null` ?

Comment: First time, I tried something like this and it gets me NullReferenceException:

`myclickbutton.Location = new Point(curr_pos_x + 55, curr_pos_y);`
`myclickbutton.ID[0] = x;`
`myclickbutton.ID[1] = y + 1;`
`originalArray[x, y + 1] = myclickbutton;`
`originalArray[x, y] = null;`

Comment: Good note @polkduran, but I don't know why this commented line with above still not working.

Comment: When do you receive that `NullRefferenceException`? At which point?

Comment: @FAngel: When I clicked on button, which were moved.

Comment: And which line exactly throws an error?

Comment: when I test:
`if ((originalArray[i, j].Name == testArray[i, j].Name)) ...`

Comment: Than - show that code. As it is currently not clear what are you doing there and why it may fail.

Comment: Where does `testArray` and `i,j` come from?

Comment: You made one of items of array to be null, now you go through all of them, null items throw you an exception. Not clear what is your question? Just check if item is not null before names are compared and you will not get an exception.

Comment: Thank you for last answer @FAngel! I forgot to test null before statements. How can I upvote you? For everybody, thanks for help -- works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made one of items of array to be null, now you go through all of them, null items throw you an exception. Just check if item is not null before names are compared and you will not get an exception

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a message saying `Null is not set`. You have commented out the line that returns the original `x` and `y` entry in the multi-dimensional array to null. What you've got at the moment is:

```
originalArray[0,0] = btn instance; 
originalArray[0,1] = temp;
```

Remove the comments from your last line and you should erase `btn instance` in `0,0`.

Comment: By which you mean do your work for you? No. Simply. Remove the comments from this line: `// originalArray[x, y] = null;`